# Form validation in magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, form-validation, password

Here is my template file content.

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="newuser_form">
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $FormKey->getFormKey();?>">
<div class="fieldset">
<h2 class="legend"><?php echo 'User Information'; ?></h2>
<ul class="form-list">

    <li>
        <label for="firstname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'First Name'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" title="<?php echo 'First Name'; ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="24" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="lastname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Last Name'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" title="<?php echo 'Last Name'; ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text required-entry"  maxlength="24" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Email Address'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo 'Email Address'; ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text required-entry validate-email"  maxlength="200" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Phone No.'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo 'Phone No.'; ?>" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="30" data-validate="{required:true}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="job_title" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Job Title/Position'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="job_title" id="job_title" title="<?php echo 'Job Title/Position'; ?>" class="input-text required-entry"  maxlength="50" data-validate="{required:true}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="department"><?php echo 'Department'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="department" id="department" title="<?php echo 'Department'; ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="50" data-validate="{required:true}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php 
            $options[] = array('value' => '', 'code'    => 'Please select...');
            $options[] = array('value' => 1, 'code' => 'Account Controller');
            $options[] = array('value' => 2, 'code' => 'Order Authorisation');
        ?>
        <label for="user_level" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Access Level'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="user_level" id="user_level" title="<?php echo 'Access Level'; ?>" class="validate-select required-entry" >
                <?php foreach ($options as $_option): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_option['value']?>"><?php echo $_option['code'] ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php $currency = '£'; ?>
        <label for="order_limit"><?php echo 'Order Value Limit'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="order_limit" id="order_limit" title="<? 
     php echo 'Order Value Limit'; ?>" class="input-text validate-currency 
    validate-number" maxlength="10" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
          </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 <div class="fieldset">
  <h2 class="legend"><?php echo 'Login Information'; ?></h2>
  <ul class="form-list">
    <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Password'; ?></label>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Confirm Password'; ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="password" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" name="confirmation" id="confirmation" data-validate="{required:true}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 <div class="buttons-set form-buttons">    
  <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo 'Save'; ?>"><span> 
  <span><?php echo 'Save'; ?></span></span></button>
  </div>
  <p class="required"><?php echo '* Required Fields'; ?></p>
 </form>
 <script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
    "#newuser_form": {
        "validation": {}
    }
  } 
 </script>
```

I am looking for code on changing drop down of Access level,

I need to remove the required validation for **Password** and **Confirm Password** fields based on the drop down value is **Account Controller**. How can this be used in Magento 2?

Please, anyone, suggest this?

Comment: try with removing "validate-cpassword"  from input

Comment: try to remove data-validate="{required:true}" from password input

Comment: Yes i need to remove and add based on drop down change, that is my requirement.